# How to test an Elasticsearch query to Get response through an ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, elasticsearch, curl

How can I connect an elasticsearch instance to an ec2 instance and then hit a get request to see if it works or not? Maybe a curl request?

for example:

```
{
        "query": {
            "fuzzy": {
                "key_name": {
                    "value": key_value,
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

on submitting such request through curl, whatever is the response, I shall be prompted.

Is there a way this can be done? My apologies, because this is the best I can portray my question on here.

Any response will be helpful thank you!

Comment: The question is not clear at all. Do you want to test connectivity between an ec2 and elasticsearch? Is your elasticsearch a managed service by aws? If yes, you only need to whitelist your ec2 ip on elasticsearch domain and that's it.

Comment: sorry for the unclarity. It's the later so I suppose whitelisting the ec2 IP on ES Domain shall help. thanks